# How to use spring security in each REST call in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to understand if there is a way to use spring security which helps my used case. Basically, I want to call spring security on each REST call in spring boot, rather than one time during the start of the application, and find the role of the user and further restrict endpoints based on the user roles.

I have 3 different rest controllers namely `/admin1/*`, `/admin2/*`, `/admin3/*`.
I have tried restricting endpoints manually as below.

```
http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/admin1/**").permitAll()
        .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/admin2/**").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated();
```

This will actually allow `/admin1/*` and `/admin2/*` APIs to work and restrict `/admin3/*`. However, my used case is as below.

In each rest call, we pass the user id in the header. I would like to use spring security on each rest call, and use the user id from the header to find the user roles from the database.

If user has *ADMIN 1* user role, we have to just enable `/admin1/*` endpoints and restrict `/admin2/*` and `/admin3/*`. Similarly, if user has *ADMIN 2* user role, we have to just enable `/admin2/*` endpoints and restrict `/admin1/*` and `/admin3/*`. In the same way, if user has *ADMIN 3* user role, we have to just enable `/admin3/*` endpoints and restrict `/admin1/*` and `/admin2/*`.

Is there a way to achieve this using spring security?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS far as I understood, you want to authenticate & authorize users on each call. True?

one way is tokenizing your REST APIs with JWT (JSON Web Token).

The example in https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-security-json-web-tokenjwt-hello-world would probably help.

I Also suggest that instead of using antMatchers In `configure` method to restrict `URL` access based on `Roles`, you use `@PreAuthorize and @PostAuthorize` annotations above the classes or methods you want to secure. This way gives you more flexibility on your restriction policies.

The example in https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-method-security also may help you with that.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That really helped. I actually played around with PreAuthorize and it actually worked. Basically, at a class level, I defined PreAuthorize which calls a method with the header parameter (userId). Using the userId value, I call the database to get the role and based on the role, restricting the endpoint. Sorry I did upvote, but it did not accept as I have less than 15 reputation points